# fprintf and the NULL terminator

Tags: c, string, null, printf

I am using fprintf to append a string to a document, here is the line I have a question about:

```
fprintf(win, bff[i - 2] != '\n' && bff[i - 2] != '\r' ? "\nmultiscreen=1" : "multiscreen=1");
```

The code works, it appends `multiscreen=1` to the next available line in the file.

But if I understand correctly wouldn't it NOT be adding a `NULL` character to the end of `multiscreen=1`? 
Does this even matter since I'm writing it to a file and the trailing `NULL` in a string is a C thing?

Or would it be more correct to use `fputs` instead of `fprintf`?

Comment: No NUL is written to the file. Just wanted to point out I'd write your line as `fprintf(win, "%smultiscreen=1", bff[i - 2] != '\n' && bff[i - 2] != '\r' ? "\n" : "")`

Comment: Strings don't end with `NULL`, they end with `\0`, which is a character whose numerical value is zero. This character is sometimes called `NUL`. It's very distinct from `NULL`, which is used in C to mean a pointer that doesn't hold a valid address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String literals automatically have a `0` as the last character in them. So you don't need to add one yourself.

The `NUL` terminator is only for `fprintf` (or whatever string function you are using) to know when to stop writing characters from the pointer; no `NUL` is actually ever written to the file.

And yes, I would recommend using `fputs` instead of `fprintf` since you're not using any of the formatting facilities of `fprintf`, unless you use pmg's suggestion in the comments to your question which does use formatting sequences.

Comment: @Minion91 yeah, I was just talking about this specific example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `NULL` in the file. It's a C convention and has nothing to do with files. You're good.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the trailing `\0` if you write to a file. It is just the way C uses to delimit the string because otherwise there is no way of knowing where the string ends